# Setting the ValueMember of a combo box is causing an error

Tags: c#, sql, controls

I'm trying to set the value member of a combo box. Two lines above this has near identical code for another field and it works fine.

```
cboCommodity.DataSource = rwDB.getCommodities();
cboCommodity.DisplayMember = "Description";
cboCommodity.ValueMember = "Com. ID#"; //<< Throws exception
```

`rwDB.getCommodities()` returns a `DataTable` object from a stored procedure that queries off of a view.

I get the Error:
`Cannot bind to the new value member.
Parameter name: value`

I've Googled around on that but nothing seems to help me.

There are no nulls in this column. I verified the column name, it exists. This column is the pk on the table. I've tried brackets `"[Com. ID#]"`. I looked at escaping the period and # too but is not needed. I'm using a column from a view in the preceding statement that works fine that contains a space. I've even looked at the locals when the execution stops and the column is listed as typed (And copy pasted the value, just to be safe), I just can't get it to work and the error is not detailed enough for me to figure it out on my own. I'm pretty stuck on something that I've done like 50 times in this project, frustrating to say the least.

Here is what the sp returns. I tried putting `Vendor` in as the `ValueMember` and it works just fine. I'm not sure what is causing the issue with that first column.

[image: Sample Image of SP return]

I'm sure this is some really silly thing that I've overlooked, as are most of the questions I ask. Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you show the code of `getCommodities`?

Comment: You need the actual column name, you seem to have the caption/description. Look at your table in SQL. Post the SQL is you can't solve it.

Comment: The description is coming off the view. The SP uses the view, I can type in point it at any other column to be `ValueMember` and it works. @Damith The `getCommodities()` function uses a generic table filling utility that works for everything. It builds the command, and returns the data table.

Comment: what is the type return from getCommodities? is it data table?

Comment: Yes. DataTable, always the result set of the SP which I verified as working. I have data in that data table, I just can't point the DataMember to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
DataTable dt = rwDB.getCommodities(); 
var column = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().FirstOrDefault().ColumnName;
cboCommodity.DataSource = dt;
cboCommodity.DisplayMember = "Description";
cboCommodity.ValueMember = column;
```

### Edit

if no other option you can change the column name

```
DataTable dt = rwDB.getCommodities();
dt.Columns["Com. ID#"].ColumnName = "ComID";
cboCommodity.DataSource = dt;
cboCommodity.DisplayMember = "Description";
cboCommodity.ValueMember = "ComID";
```

Comment: @Bmo as alternative you can change the column name. But keep this question open.

Comment: That did it. I didn't think to change the table value...thought the referenced schema would be read only. I guess it's just a copy anyway. Thanks for the help, inelegant, but functional.